# JFlex successor

Tags: java, parser-generator, jflex

[JFlex](http://jflex.de/) is quite old scanner generator; last version (1.4.3) has been released in 2009, and v1.5 is on trunk for a long time. I wonder if someone has found good successor and replacement for JFLex? That would be a scanner generator that can process more-less the same grammar files; and yet to produce better (read: faster) code - JFLex still can be improved in some areas (table optimization etc). I do see that IntelliJ IDEA uses patched JFlex (haven't got a chance to try it yet).

So have you used some scanner generator recently (or a full parser) that can replace JFlex rather easily?

Please, if you answer this, give us some details in how the new lib was better for you.

EDIT: on JFlex repo, there is a branch called **1.4.3-fixes**, and I am currently using that one as it contain some important patches. There is also latest 1.5.0 snapshot, yet I am not sure if it is production ready.

Comment: You were just a little impatient. JFlex 1.5 was released in March 2014.

Comment: 'little', funny :) Thank you for letting me know for the new version.